# Dragging out unused quantifier?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, quantifiers

Here are two propositions:

1.∃x(F(x)∧∀yF(y)∧x≠y→A(x,y))

2.∃x∀y(F(x)∧F(y)∧x≠y→A(x,y))

domain of x: the whole body of students and faculty members

domain of y: the whole body of students and faculty members

F(x): x is a faculty member;

A(x,y): x has asked y a question

The expression 1 is supposed to mean in English that "there exists a faculty member who has asked every other faculty member a question."

Personnally I think that the expression 2 means the same thing as expression 1, since there's no y appearing before ∀y, we can drag ∀y out in front. But my TA says the expression is not equivalent. But I don't get how they aren't? We can't drag ∀y in front even though there's no y before it? Why?

edit: as pointed out by @Jair Taylor the expressions are without clarifying parentheses, but I'm assuming that it's like this:

1.∃x{F(x)∧∀y[F(y)∧(x≠y)→A(x,y)]}

2.∃x∀y[F(x)∧F(y)∧(x≠y)→A(x,y)]

Comment: These propositions are pretty ambiguous without some more parentheses, unless there are specified order of operations.

Comment: Order of operation is ∧ before →, and from left to right.

Comment: I agree with @JairTaylor about the need for parentheses. Once the parentheses are added (reasonably), your argument will be correct. The quantifier $\forall y$ can be "pulled out". Quite generally, if $\phi$ and $\psi$ arre formulas and $y$ is not free in $\phi$, then $\phi\land\forall y\,\psi$ is logically equivalent to $\forall y\,(\phi\land\psi)$.  (I'm presupposing the usual convention in first-order logic that the domain of discourse is not empty.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass what do you mean by y is not free in ϕ? Does it mean that y doesn't appear in ϕ?

Comment: For a variable to be free in a formula means that the variable has occurrences in that formula that are not in the scope of any quantifier. (In particular, if $y$ doesn't occur in $\phi$ then it isn't free in $\phi$.) If you have a textbook, it should give a detailed definition of "free".

Comment: @AndreasBlass but then I don't get why <Quite generally, if ϕ and ψ arre formulas and y is not free in ϕ, then ϕ∧∀yψ is logically equivalent to ∀y(ϕ∧ψ)> . If y is not free, and u add another quantifier to it, aren't you changing it's bounding condition? By not free it means it's bounded by some quantifier right?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last comment. I'm not adding a quantifier; I'm moving the quantifier $\forall y$. After the move, it applies to exactly the same occurrences of $y$ as it did before the move, namely those that are free in $\psi$. Any $y$'s in $\phi$ were already bound by quantifiers in $\phi$ before the move, and they remain bound by the same quantifiers in $\phi$ (not by the moved one) after the move.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I think I got it now. It's because if y is bounded, then adding another bound that is always equal or greater than the existing bound will not change the bounding condition. But what about a free y? In that case why you can't drag it out?

Comment: I'm beginning to suspect that you're confusing "bound" with "bounded". An occurrence of a variable is bound if it is in the scope of a quantifier; a quantity is bounded is it is required to be $\leq$ some other specified quantity. (Unfortunately, "bound" is the past participle of the verb "to bind", and "bounded" is the past participle of "to bound". I make no attempt to explain why English is like that, but it is.)

Comment: Hmm I don't know. I think I need to read more about the definition of free and bound, anyway thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Assuming that the issue about parentheses has been settled, you are right; the two formulas (after editing) are equivalent. See [Prnex normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form#Conjunction_and_disjunction) : $\forall x(\phi )\land \psi$  is equivalent to $\forall x(\phi \land \psi )$ when $x$ does not appear as a free variable of $\psi$. In your case, $\psi$ is $Fx$ (no $y$) and we are moving quantifier $\forall y$.